# javascript get access_token almost got it need support

Tags: javascript

i want to get the access_token value but instead it gets id_token which i do not want.
here is the code i have and i kindly will appreciate it if you can share a fix to what i want.

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central'));
```

kindly look at this attachment below picture so you know what am trying to get.

[image]

Update code

```
alert(Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central')))[2]);
```

brings Access_Token Name only no value?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBkdA.png)

Comment: You want localstorage key name?

Comment: Like `Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central')))[0]`

Comment: access_token value i want

Comment: alert(localStorage.getItem('Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central')))[0]'));    i added like this so i can get a alert message with the key. but nothing showing up no alert

Comment: It is not the right order. You are quoting the script used to extract the JSON. `console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central')))[0]);` look in the console for errors too

Comment: ok now  your code  alert(Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central')))[2]);  i set to 2 now it outputs access_token name but not value with it ?

Comment: post1 updated with your code please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
ak=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central'));

alert(JSON.stringify(ak['access_token']));
```

this turns the JSON into a Js array so you can get the parameter you want

Comment: ak=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central'));
alert(ak['access_token]);   tested i dont get popup. the browser am using in another app i cant use console.log. so i use alert better off. anyways this is not poping up alert ?

Comment: ak=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('oidc.user:https://accounts.zerotier.com/auth/realms/zerotier:zt-central'));
alert(JSON.stringify(ak['access_token']));